# Bash get docker image ID automatically

Tags: linux, bash, docker, awk, docker-image

I'm trying to run a few docker commands in my linux machine:

```
1- sudo docker load -i test.tar
2- sudo docker tag bf46cff9b182 test:v1.0
3- sudo docker run -it --network host -v /home/logs:/home/test/test/logs test:v1.0
```

But I would like to make a `runme.sh` and execute all in one run. The problem is that ImageID `bf46cff9b182` is dynamiccally changing everytime. So I need to somehow `pipe` it from the output of the `load` command, which is in fact possible.

The output of `load` is like this:

```
Loaded image ID: sha256:bf46cff9b1829b50e28f6485c923efff94799dd84cbf747dc86f6e5d006f2a81
```

On Linux it is shown as this:

```
4f512fb4b0ea: Loading layer  5.079MB/5.079MB
Loaded image ID: sha256:b6c3df68a9365ccb0935a835aa332b29db780cb7e81eac83acf717b2                                                                             de779073
```

And the `12` characters after `sha256` would be `bf46cff9b182`, which would me my Image ID inserted in command #2 above.

How can I write a bash command to do this automatically?

Comment: As an aside, add yourself to the `docker` group so you don't have to `sudo docker` all the time. What's the point of a container if you have to be root anyway?

Comment: I'm new to docker. How can I do that?

Comment: On Debianish platforms, `sudo adduser "$USER" docker` where `$USER` is your own account name. You can then `exec sg docker` to join the group, or log out and back in again. Other platforms probably have a similar arrangement, though it's likely to differ in the details.

Comment: Yeah looks like it is different on my centos. Will figure it out thanks!

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/ has some instructions. https://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2015/08/why-we-dont-let-non-root-users-run-docker-in-centos-fedora-or-rhel/ seems to indicate that this is not enabled by default on RPM platforms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple `sed` script to extract the sha256.

```
docker load -i test.tar |
sed -n 's/^Loaded image ID: sha256:\([0-9a-f]*\).*/\1/p'
```

You can now capture this into a variable, or pipe it onward with `xargs`:

```
docker load -i test.tar |
sed -n 's/^Loaded image ID: sha256:\([0-9a-f]*\).*/\1/p' |
xargs -i docker tag {} test:v1.0
```

Comment: Good. But can you post a full answer? In combined with the other one? `res=$(sudo docker load -i test.tar | sed -n 's/^Loaded image ID: sha256://p')
id=${res:0:12}`

Comment: There is no need to trim it down to just the first 12 characters. You are allowed but not required to abbreviate.  If you want to, trimming to 12 characters is easy with `sed -nE 's/^Loaded image ID: sha256:([0-9a-f]{12}).*/\1/p'` (though this isn't entirely portable).

Comment: That `p` goes until a space? There is some extra string after the long hashcode, if you see above.

Comment: Ouch, that's weird. Updated. Does `docker load -q` get rid of the chaff?

Comment: I need `sudo` so shall I add it in the beginning of each command (even the docker tag one)?

Comment: Yeah, `xargs -i sudo docker tag ...` but maybe a better solution woull be `sudo ./yourscript` and keep the `sudo` out of the script itself? (I'm divided; on the other hand you want to run code under `sudo` unnecessarily.)

Comment: oh ok. Will try it now.

Answer (score 2):

You can store the id in a variable that you can use in next command.

```
res=$(docker load ...)
id=${res:25:12}
docker tag $id ...
```

This gets a substring from offset 25 (I hope I counted correctly) with length 12

Edit:
I found out, you dont even need sed to extract the hash in a "clean" way.

```
res=$(docker load ...)
hash=${res##*sha256:}
id=${hash:0:12}
docker tag $id ...
```

Comment: Can you make it cleaner with `grep`?! Maybe find `sha256:` and get 12 lengths after that. I'm wondering there might be some extra lines there.

Comment: ok. I updated my question. The output slightly differs on Linux. If you can post a `sed` or `awk` based answer, it would work.

Answer (score 0):

From [docker load](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/) documentation:

> It restores both images and tags.

So, you could just use the tag that the image had before doing **[docker save](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/)**.

Comment: When saving, it already has the tags and a name. But after loading, it changes to `<none>`.

Comment: This is because saving using IMAGE-ID is ambiguous. Save using REPOSITORY:TAG and both will preserved.